# bad operand types for binary operator+(JAVA PROGRAM)

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing my class lab in java.

This program is to output winning team by summing total score. 
(there is blue team and white team in the input file with member's first name and each member's score. )

I have error bad operand types for binary operator.(sumArray) I think it is because int type + int []. can anybody help me out? if you see any other problem, please let me know. I guess there is lots of error except for this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// declaration of the class
public class Bowling
{

// declaration of main program 
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

// 1. connect to input file
Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader("bowling.txt"));

    // declare arrays below
String Team, Member;
int teamw, teamb, Score;

    // 2) initialize array accumulators to zero
    teamw=0;
    teamb=0;
    int [] white_score = new int[3]; 
    String [] white_member = new String[3]; 
    int [] blue_score = new int[3];
    String [] blue_member = new String[3];
    // 3) display a descriptive message
System.out.println(
        "This program reads the lines from the file bowling.txt to determine\n"
        + "the winner of a bowling match.  The winning team, members and scores\n"
           + "are displayed on the monitor.\n");

    // 4) test Scanner.eof() condition
    while (fin.hasNext())
       {
       // 5) attempt to input next line from file
       Member = fin.next();
       Team = fin.next();
       Score = fin.nextInt();
       // 6) test team color is blue
       // 7) then store blue member and score
       // 8) increase blue array accumulator
       // 9) else store white member and score
        // 10) increase white array accumulator
       if (Team.equals("Blue"))
       {
           blue_member[teamb]=Member;
           blue_score[teamb] = Score;
           teamb++;
       }
       else
       {
           white_member[teamw]= Member;
           white_score[teamw]= Score;
           teamw++;
       }
    }

    // 11) if blue team score is larger
    // 12) then display blue team as winner
    // 13) else display white team as winner
    if(sumArray(blue_score)>sumArray(white_score))
    {
        printArray("Blue", blue_member, blue_score);
    }
    else
    {
        printArray("White", white_member, white_score);
    }

    // 14 disconnect from the input file
fin.close();
}
public static int sumArray(int[] Score)
{
    int sum=0;

    for ( int i=0; i<Score.length; i++)
     sum = sum+Score;           ////HERE IS problem!!!!!!

    return sum;
}
public static void printArray(String Team, String[] Member, int[] Score)
    {
    for(int i=0; i<Member.length; i++)
    System.out.printf("winning team:"+Team+"\n"+Member+":"+Score);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
sum += Score[i];
```

to add elements of the array inside `for` loop.

You are getting error because you can not add `int` with array. In Java you can not use `+` operator directly with arrays.

Comment: thanks! here is more question. after fixing it with Score[i], there is no syntax error. however, running the program makes lots of weird character.(like..
winning team:Blue
[Ljava.lang.String;@63fd26:[I@c0235awinning team:Blue
[Ljava.lang.String;@63fd26:[I@c0235awinning team:Blue
[Ljava.lang.String;@63fd26:[I@c0235a)

what is the problem??

Comment: @JustinJuntaeKim That's what happens when you try to print an array. You have to iterate over it and print each element individually.

Comment: As  Bethany Louise pointed out, either you should iterate over each elment in array to properly stringify elements of array or if you don't want to iterate, use `List<Integer>`.

Comment: @BethanyLouise  I got you. This is the first time to see java. and I just started to learn about array this week. I hope that it will get better if i see over and over ;)